# Script changes textfield color but does not show unless field is selected

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I made this PDF calculator to show when over/under 25%. The script works somewhat, unless I select the new opening field you would not know it's working and as soon as you select another field it reverts to acrobat standard textfield color, the idea is have new opening field stay green or red as the form gets get filled out only when resetting it should revert normal color.

Can someone help me out, what am I missing here?

Thank you.

[calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe237.png)

```
var v1 = this.getField("newOpening").value;
var v2 = this.getField("calculatedTotal").value;

if (v1 < v2) {
   bg = color.green;
} else if (v1 > v2) {
   bg = color.red; 
} 

event.target.fillColor = bg;
```

Comment: Where (field and event) are you calling the function?

Comment: I modified this script from someone doing something similar to what I want to accomplish, I want to add a function after I get the fill color resolved that's why I left it in there

Comment: If the field is already being calculated and you just want to change the fill color, you should be adding that code to the format script... is that where you have this?

Comment: It's in Calculate, I tried it in format Custom like you suggested and in Validate. so far I get best result in Calculate with same issue

Comment: @Max Wyss, can you help with the proper function and event for this script, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code should actually work. However, it has a few issues.

The very first issue is that the variable bg is not explicitely defined. The way it comes along in the original script means that it is a global variable, which can be accessed and modified in any way from within the document. Better explicitely define it.

Another issue is that there is no mentioned trigger for the Calculate sequence. So, you would need either an active element (essentially, a button, but a link or page event would do as well), or you would need some field event which initiates the field event sequence.

To say it simply, if you'd enter a value in any field in the document, a calculation would happen, and then the script, if assigned to a Calculate action would be executed.

There is one thing you would have to think about. In your script, you make a differentiation between v1 smaller than v2, and v1 greater than v2. What should happen if both values are equal? You might also make sure that you actually treat the values in the fields as numbers. Easiest is to set their format to Number. Otherwise, you could multiply their values with 1.

A slightly revised version of your code would look like this (assuming that if both values are the same (as also in the default state of the form), the background will be white):

```
var v1 = this.getField("newOpening") ;
var v2 = this.getField("calculatedTotal") ;
var bg = color.white ;

if (v1.value*1 < v2.value*1) {
   bg = color.green;
} else {
   if (v1.value*1 > v2.value*1) {
      bg = color.red; 
   } 
}

event.target.fillColor = bg;
```

That should do it. If you still encounter issues, you might consider using the explicite color definition arrays for the colors, as in

`["RGB", 1, 0, 0]` for `color.red`

`["RGB", 0, 1, 0]` for `color.green`

`["RGB", 1, 1, 1]` for `color.white`

Comment: working the same as before using arrays or declaring global variable but It did work when I changed fillcolor to textColor on event.target.